# Django image scraping then using sort thumbnail

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a Reddit clone, and this is my last piece I ne d to finish the job. I want image scraping from the url user provides. I have no idea how to start this though. I checked out Reddit code, and it seems like there are different functions for different sites. Any guidance to get me started? Any tutorial I can take a look at?

Comment: Are you looking for img urls?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). It should get the job done.

Comment: I did, I write functions to scrap images using beautiful soup then how do I incorporate with thumbnail and views.py..... Is this suppose to be this complex?